# Python unsubscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

What does `unsubscriptable` mean in the context of a TypeError as in:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

EDIT:
Short code example that results in this phenomena.

```
a=[[1,2],[5,3],5,[5,6],[2,2]]
for b in a:
    print b[0]

> 1
> 5
> TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: Please include the code that produced the message.  Please include the **smallest** sample of code that actually produces this error message.

Comment: Good start.  Thanks.  Step 2.  Print the values of `b`.  You can cut down the example to just one specific values of `b` that has this problem.  Can you do that next step, too?

Comment: @S.Lott - Ok should be more clear now.

Comment: Finally, What is the value of `b` when the error is printed?  Include that in your question.

Comment: If you used a print debug before posting this question like  ```print "debug: %r" % b; print b[0]``` then you would be able to find the the issue byself ;). It took me 2 minutes to understand your problem.

Comment: In general, it simply is when `you are trying to get an element out of something that isn’t a dictionary, list, or tuple`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It means you tried treating an integer as an array. For example:

```
a = 1337
b = [1,3,3,7]
print b[0] # prints 1
print a[0] # raises your exception
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem in your sample code is that the array "a" contains two different types: it has 4 2-element lists and one integer.  You are then trying to sub-script every element in "a", including the integer element.

In other words, your code is effectively doing:

```
print [1,2][0]
print [5,3][0]
print 5[0]
print [5,6][0]
print [2,2][0]
```

That middle line where it does "5[0]" is what is generating the error.

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to lookup an array subscript of an int:

```
>>> 1[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

That is, square brackets `[]` are the subscript operator. If you try to apply the subscript operator to an object that does not support it (such as not implementing `__getitem__()`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this converting my variable from list to array!

```
import numpy as np
my_list = API.get_list()
my_array = np.array(my_list)
```

Even working and be a false positive, this solved my 'problem'